# FLUTTER | GetX | Getting cannot emit events to disposed clients from app as a unusual behaviour

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmzjh.jpg)

I am getting this issue randomly in my flutter app dont understand why and how its comming. not able to reproduce it on debug mode.
Seems to a issue with the statemanagemnt solution, i am using GetX Builder method, with all controllers initialized at OnInit method.

Please Help

I tried to call the destruct method, tried to call all controllers using a binding but i am still facing this issue and its quite random.

Comment: Can you add the the log of the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.